# how to force lyrics under manually beamed notes

Tags: lilypond, lyrics, beaming

If I do not specify any manual beams and let the algorithm do it, lyrics are put at each note:

```
\relative {
  g'4 e8 g8 g4 e8 g
}
\addlyrics { a b c d e f }
```

[image: Lyrics correctly aligned with note heads]

But if I do it manually and forbid the algorithm to do it, there will be no lyrics under all non-first notes of a beam:

```
\relative {
  \autoBeamOff
   g'4 e8[ g8] g4 e8[ g]
}
\addlyrics { a b c d e f }
```

[image: Lyrics mis-aligned as melismas]

**How do I force lyrics in the latter case to be as in the first?**

I'm using Lilypond 2.20.0.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is the expected behavior: LilyPond by default considers beams and ties as indicating melismas. See [Multiple notes to one syllable](http://lilypond.org/doc/v2.14/Documentation/notation/common-notation-for-vocal-music#multiple-notes-to-one-syllable) in the LilyPond manual.

To override this, insert the line `\set melismaBusyProperties = #'()`, which is explained in the same manual section as linked above.

```
\relative {
  \autoBeamOff
  \set melismaBusyProperties = #'()
   g'8 e8[ g8] g4 e8[ g]
}
\addlyrics { a b c d e f }
```

To specifically exclude manual beams from indicating melismas, but keep this behavior for ties, use the following:

```
\set melismaBusyProperties = #'(melismaBusy slurMelismaBusy tieMelismaBusy)
```

Note that `beamMelismaBusy` is excluded from the list, which means manual beams won't affect melismas.